# Why two instances of activity is getting created after reboot?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a boot receiver which receives BOOT_COMPLETED event and launches the default activity for my application as follows:

```
if(MyApplication.GetCurrentActivity()==null)
{
    Intent mActivityIntent = new Intent(context, LauncherActivity.class);
    mActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(mActivityIntent);
}
```

I'm setting the activity after starting it. GetCurrentActivity() will return null if there are no activities launched or the last launched activity.
So far there is no problem.

But if the user touches the app icon before the LauncherActivity has been launched, two instances of the same activities are created as they are in two different tasks (I guess). How to prevent this and launch only one instance of the activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
if(MyApplication.GetCurrentActivity()==null)
{
  Intent mActivityIntent = new Intent(context, LauncherActivity.class);

  mActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

  mActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

  startActivity(mActivityIntent);

  finish();
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Then you can use *[FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)* -

This flag will cause the launched activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.-

```
if(MyApplication.GetCurrentActivity()==null)
    {
      Intent mActivityIntent = new Intent(context, LauncherActivity.class);

      mActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)

      startActivity(mActivityIntent);

      finish();
    }
```

For example -

> Consider a task consisting of four activities: `A, B, C, D`. If `D`
>   calls `startActivity()` with an Intent that resolves to the component
>   of activity B, then B will be brought to the front of the history
>   stack, with this resulting order: `A, C, D, B`.

Comment: I don't want to clear all other activities which are in the foreground. I just want just one instance of that activity and if its not in foreground let it be. I don't want it to bring to foreground unless the user wants it.

Comment: What is the significance of FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY here?

Comment: FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY  - If set, the new activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished.

Comment: What will happen if the user tries to start the application even before the boot is completed? Is there any native method to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 <activity
        android:name="name"
        android:label="label"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
 </activity>
```

This launch only one instance of the activity. Now, you can implement onNewIntent().

Hope it helps you :)